# How to search for a file with an unknown directory and delete it?

Tags: c#, winforms, search, delete-file

I am trying to make a program that will search for a file on all hard disks and delete it once it is found. But I don't know how to get started in doing this?

Also I am fairly new to coding in some aspects of C# would it be possible to get an example of how to use the code in action? If so that would be very helpful.

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you mean. What exactly is “unknown directory”? Does that mean I have search all disks on the computer? Can you give us an example?

Comment: yes that is what i mean i just changed my post to match what you asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DriveInfo.GetDrives() to get all the drives. Then Directory.GetFiles() on each drive's RootDirectory (or any of the other Directory methods to iterate through the drives). You should probably check DriveType on each and omit any types that are readonly like CDROM and limited access network drives. Note that this can take some time so you should provide the user with ample feedback.

You should also check the file attributes to ensure you have write access. Or at least catch any exceptions that File.Delete() can throw.

- [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)
- [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)
- [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

Comment: When doing file operations like this, you should always except them to fail. If you check for write access, somebody could have change the privileged between you checked and the delete operation. Or the file could have been deleted in some other way in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
FileInfo[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "file.ext", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This is not tested code, but it should return an array of FileInfo objects, one for each file that was found on drive C:\ which matches the given name. Specifying SearchOption.AllDirectories makes sure that all folders are searched to any depth.

If you need to search multiple drives, you'll need to call this for each one, possibly in a loop.

The documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx.

Comment: +1 But change to: `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "file.ext", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to search some folders for a file. Start with methods from [the Directory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ta62wh3.aspx), like Directory.GetDirectories and Directory.GetFiles to find your file.

Comment: how would i just search an entire hard disc for a file instead of having to search specific folders? because I am not sure what folder the file is in.

Answer (score 0):

Besides [Richard Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122740/richard-cox)'s answer, if you want to know how to iterate through all subdirectories – see the second example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx